# I'm getting the same errors whenever adding a Github package to my swift project

Tags: php, mysql, swift, mariadb

[image: The error I'm getting:]

When adding a package to my swift project I get these errors.

I'm trying to connect my swift application to a mariadb database so I can create, modify data.

I've tried the mariadb-connector-c method by perfect.org and I get the same errors In the picture.

An API would be helpful too If you know one.
If you know another simple method or how to fix these errors when adding a package please help.

Thanks!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), images are hard to read and troubleshoot. Please [edit] your post and add the code here as text. Be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: How is this issue related to PHP?